# AWS CloudWatch doest show the logs of ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a Cloudwatch group and liked it to ECS container definition using Terraform:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "ecs_log" {
name = "/fargate/simat-${terraform.workspace}"
tags = {
env         = "${terraform.workspace}"
 }
}
```

and below the task definition :

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "simat_task_definition" {
 family                   = "tsk-family"
 task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
 execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
 requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
 network_mode             = "awsvpc"
 cpu                      = 512
 memory                   = 1024

 container_definitions = jsonencode([
   {
    name      = "simat"
    image     = "app_1"
    cpu       = 512
    memory    = 1024
    essential = true
    log_configuration = {
     logDriver = "awslogs"
     options = {
       "awslogs-group"         = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.ecs_log.name
       "awslogs-region"        = var.region
       "awslogs-stream-prefix" = "ecs"
     }
   },
   portMappings = [
     {
      containerPort = 80
      hostPort      = 80
       }
      ]
     }
    ])
   }
```

this is my ECS execution role policy: I think I added all required permission

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
name = "policy-$var.application-ecstask-exe-$terraform.workspace-${var.region}-1"
role = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.id
policy = jsonencode({
 "Version" : "2012-10-17",
 "Statement" : [
   {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Action" : [
      "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
      "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
      "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "ssm:GetParameters",
      "sns:*",
      "cloudwatch:*",
      "events:PutEvents"
    ],
    "Resource" : "*"
   }
 ]
})
```

This code makes ECS a task definition but no cloud watch link to it. what am I missing?

Comment: Check that your ecs_task_execution_role has permission to put logs to that particular log group.

Comment: slightly off topic but in modern versions of terraform you don't need ${} and can simply do `env = terraform.workspace`

Comment: added the role policy in the question

Comment: Yes, the IAM role looks good. Does an empty log stream get created at all? Or no log stream gets created?

Comment: Have you tried to create the LogGroup resource?